# Can a query that uses the same filtered table for both unpivoting and joining be written without repetition?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, unpivot, union-all

Consider the following query:

```sql
create function unpivoter(@TableID int)
returns table
as
return
(
    select a, b
    from
    (
        select foo1, foo2, foo3, foo4
        from table1
        where table1.id = @TableID
    ) tab_in
    unpivot
       (a for b in (foo1, foo2, foo3, foo4)) tab_out

    union all

        select t3.a, t3.b,
        from table1 t1
        join t2 on t1.id = t2.id
        join t3 on t3.id = t2.id
        where t1.id = @TableID

    union all
    
        select t4.a, t4.b,
        from table1 t1
        join t4 on t4.id = t4.id
        where t1.id = @TableID
)
```

this is obviously highly repetitive. Two things stand out

1. `table1` is given the same filter thrice. I'd replace it with a CTE, but the select list is different between the first use the rest, so this could have a big performance hit depending on the indexing situation.
2. The `union all`s all look very similar. The fact that I could have also written the `unpivot` as a set of three `union all`s suggests that the two `union all`s that are currently within the query should somehow be merged in to the `unpivot`.

**Is there anything in T-SQL that can tackle these two problems?**

Comment: "I'd replace it with a CTE, but the select list is different between the first use the rest, so this could have a big performance hit depending on the indexing situation" - No that isn't correct. It is fine to just have a CTE with `SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE id = @TableID` and then reference that CTE multiple times and SQL Server will sort it out and use the most appropriate indexing for the requirements per reference. The CTE references are inlined as I thought you knew from previous questions

Comment: e.g. see https://dbfiddle.uk/gxC7_5WZ

Comment: @MartinSmith Excellent point. Clearly, I have more to learn.

Comment: SQL is a declarative language ; you use the syntax to define the problem, not the mechanism to solve it (the execution plan is the cost based optimiser's solution). Don't treat SQL like an imperative language.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not entirely, however you can avoid looking up `table1` multiple times by putting the `UNION ALL` in an `APPLY`.

Use a `(VALUES` constructor instead of `UNPIVOT`, it is far more flexible.

```sql
CREATE OR ALTER FUNCTION dbo.unpivoter (@TableID int)
RETURNS TABLE
AS RETURN

SELECT
  u.a,
  u.b
FROM table1 t1

CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT
      tab_out.a,
      tab_out.b
    FROM (VALUES
        ('foo1', t1.foo1),
        ('foo2', t1.foo2),
        ('foo3', t1.foo3),
        ('foo4', t1.foo4)
    ) tab_out(a, b)

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
      t3.a,
      t3.b,
    FROM t2
    JOIN t3 ON t3.id = t2.id
    WHERE t2.id = t1.id

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
      t4.a,
      t4.b,
    FROM t4
    WHERE t4.id = t1.id
) u
WHERE t1.id = @TableID;
```

You could also replace the `VALUES` with a few `UNION ALL`, bu it's more verbose.

```sql
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT
      'foo1' AS a,
      t1.foo1 AS b

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
      'foo2' AS a,
      t1.foo2 AS b

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
      'foo3' AS a,
      t1.foo3 AS b

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
      'foo4' AS a,
      t1.foo4 AS b

    UNION ALL
```

Comment: Damn, nice, you beat me by one second :)

Comment: Very very good. I had a feeling that `CROSS APPLY` would do the trick. It might be worth spelling out in this answer why the same trick won't work with `UNPIVOT`. I have reasonable guesses, but it seems best for a "prefer `CROSS APPLY` to `UNPIVOT`" answer to spell out why `UNPIVOT` can't solve the problem.

Comment: It's not strictly true that you can't use `UNPIVOT`, you can put *that* into the `APPLY` https://dbfiddle.uk/-ERoq_rW note the lack of a `FROM` in the subquery.

Comment: Unqualified references in sub-queries just confuses people, especially those newer to SQL.

Comment: In the fiddle with the unpivot

Comment: Ah sorry I kind of dashed that off

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE FUNCTION unpivoter(@TableID INT)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN
(
    WITH FilteredTable AS (
        SELECT foo1, foo2, foo3, foo4
        FROM table1
        WHERE table1.id = @TableID
    ),
    UnpivotedData AS (
        SELECT a, b
        FROM FilteredTable
        UNPIVOT (
            a FOR b IN (foo1, foo2, foo3, foo4)
        ) AS u
    ),
    JoinedData AS (
        SELECT t3.a, t3.b
        FROM table1 t1
        JOIN t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
        JOIN t3 ON t3.id = t2.id
        WHERE t1.id = @TableID

        UNION ALL

        SELECT t4.a, t4.b
        FROM table1 t1
        JOIN t4 ON t1.id = t4.id
        WHERE t1.id = @TableID
    )
    SELECT * FROM UnpivotedData
    UNION ALL
    SELECT * FROM JoinedData
);
```

In the above code I have used three CTEs: `FilteredTable`, `UnpivotedData`, and `JoinedData`. The `FilteredTable` CTE filters the necessary data from `table1` once and is used by both the unpivoting and joining parts of the query. The `UnpivotedData` CTE performs the unpivoting operation. The `JoinedData` CTE combines the two `UNION ALL` blocks.